# onclick function using Laravel is not defined only after compiling the JS file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js, laravel-5

So I'm working with Laravel 5.4 and in the project I have a blade view with this element:

```
<a onclick="getStuff(this)"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

But when I click on the element I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: getStuff is not defined
```

This is in the external JS I'm using:

```
$(window).on("load", function () { code... }
...
function getStuff(aElement) { code... }
```

The thing is, all of it actually works perfectly when I add the external JS file directly into the `public/js` folder in the main directory (which is the only folder that the blade view can have access to). But, as I take it, this is bad practice. What I'm doing ("the Laravel way") is to add the JS file in the `resource/assets/js` folder and then running `npm run dev` to compile it so it automatically adds a compiled version of the file into the `public/js` folder. It is after doing that when it doesn't work.

I also think the compilation is moderately successful because I can run everything in the JS file that doesn't require an interaction with the page to run. It's only when I try to call it with something like that `onclick` that it doesn't work.

Comment: You could start by using the Chrome/IE dev tools to ensure that the script you suspect contains your getStuff method is actually being served to the client and ensure that it's actually there, and ten throw in a breakpoint to see if the method is getting called or not

Comment: @Tor Yes, it's getting served to the client with the `getStuff` function inside of it. All the code inside `$(window).on("load", function () {} )` runs when entering the page and works fine. The problem is the functions defined outside of that, that are called by `onclick` attributes. I don't get the breakpoint part, it wouldn't work because when I click nothing runs in the JS, given that it doesn't even find the function.

Comment: Hmm does anything in `$(window).on("load", function () {} )` create or set up the `<a>` that use `getStuff`? I don't think this is the case, but are the elements being created and bound to the function before the function exists? Try changing the order so that `getStuff` is defined before `$(window).on("load", function () {} )`

Comment: @Tor  no, nothing is related. Tried changing the order and it didn't work